# How add field to the email report?

Tags: woocommerce, field, addition

How add field to the email report??
http://www.evernote.com/l/Ac2uV87BrP9G9L7eKZplR1x3LrsGs-Yfsm8/
and 
how add field to the order page
http://www.evernote.com/l/Ac1m-Ah7v71P9Zv3dmbIPXlHdxnrr9T7WkA/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a sensible question.

Comment: Please do not repeat tags in question titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field in email report using the following code

```
function wdm_custom_order_item_details($total_rows, $object){

    $total_rows['custom Message']= array(
           'label' =>  'My Custom Message',
           'value' => 'Custom information i want to see in order emails',
        );
    return $total_rows;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals','wdm_custom_order_item_details',10,2);
```

here the output will be

[image]

and to add field to the order page use this code

```
function wdm_admin_order_panel_after_shipping_address($order){
    //use $order to get the details you want related to that order and display it here.
    echo "<div><h4>My Custom Information</h4><p>Custom information i want to see in order details</p></div>"; 
}
//to add text after Shipping address of an order in admin panel
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'wdm_admin_order_panel_after_shipping_address' ,10,1);
```

here the output will be

[image]

Tested. Let me know if it worked for you.